# Setting Default 666 Permissions for Specific File Types (.xlms, .png .pdf...) in Linux Using ColdFusion

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod, acl

I am working on a project using ColdFusion on a Linux system, and I need to programmatically set default permissions (666) for files with specific extensions (.pdf, .xlsx, .png, .html, .zip).
Despite using various `chmod` and `setfacl` commands, I have not achieved the desired result.

I want that whenever any file uploaded by ColdFusion application on directory it should get 666 permission by-default so that any can rename the uploaded file.

The folder has owner `nobody` and `nogroup`. Here are the commands I have tried:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w folder/
sudo chmod -R g+s folder/
setfacl -R -m "default:user::rwx,default:group::rwx,default:other::rwx" foldername/
```

**Note:-** When I'm uploading file from terminal it's getting 666 permission, but when I creating and uploading file from ColdFusion program it's getting rw-r-r i.e 644 permission. So what should I do to get 666 permission on the file?

Comment: The permission to rename a file has nothing to do with the file's permissions, it only depends on the _directory_ permissions. What exactly are you trying to do? Is it only renaming? Or do you need to be able to edit as well?

Comment: @terdon , I want to rename the file by ColdFusion program, because all the file creating on the folder is created by ColdFusion program.

Comment: If you just want to rename, then change the permissions of the _directory_, not the file.

Comment: Yes, but what permission I have to give on directory, so that I'm able to rename the file when ColdFusion programmatically upload file.